# stream.Take(16) <-- Make array of 16bytes?

Tags: .net, stream

I feel silly asking but...

Using C#/.NET I have a stream and I wrote my own extension function to read short (or byte was built in).

Is there something i can use which will create an array of X length (16 in my example) and return a byte array of that? Throw an exception otherwise? ReadByte does that and is built in. There should be something like what i am asking already in the .NET framework

Comment: BinaryReader.ReadBytes() jumps to mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there something i can use which will create an array of X length (16 in my example) and return a byte array of that?

For byte data, you can just call [Stream.Read](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.read.aspx):

```
byte[] values = new byte[16];
int read = theStream.Read(values, 0, 16);
// Make sure you read all 16...
```

Or, you could use [BinaryReader.ReadBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader.readbytes.aspx):

```
byte[] values = theStream.ReadBytes(16);
```

If you want to handle short data, I'd make an extension method that did this for [BinaryReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader.aspx):

```
public static short[] ReadInt16Array(this BinaryReader reader, int elementsToRead)
{
     short[] results = new short[elementsToRead];
     for (int i=0;i<elementsToRead;++i)
        results[i] = reader.ReadInt16();
     return results;
}
```

Comment: Except you'd want to use the return value of `Read` and potentially loop, of course, instead of assuming it would read all 16 bytes in one go...